# How can I randomly run for loop in sh of git action normally?

Tags: bash, sh, github-actions

How can I randomly run for loop in sh of git action normally?

There is a github repository with daily commits here.

for github action

The yml file below exists.

```
name: planting-grass

on:
   schedule:
     - cron: '0 0 * * *'

jobs:
  task:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set current date
        id: date
        run: echo "::set-output name=date::$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')"
      - name: Execute commands
        run: sh ./task.sh ${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}
      - name: Commit files
        run: |
          git config --global user.name "$(git --no-pager log --format=format:'%an' -n 1)"
          git config --global user.email "$(git --no-pager log --format=format:'%ae' -n 1)"
          git add date.txt
          git commit -m ${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}
      - name: Push changes
        uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          branch: ${{ github.ref }}
```

This yml runs task.sh.
task.sh looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "DATE: $1" >> date.txt
```

everything works fine.

However, in data.txt, one line per day is accumulated.

I want to accumulate lines between 1 and 100 in data.txt.

Where can I edit to use the above function?

Then I tried the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

range=100
number=$((RANDOM % range))

while [ "$i" -le "$number" ]; do
    echo "DATE: $1" >> date.txt
done
```

```
#!/bin/bash

range=100
number=$((RANDOM % range))
i=0

while (( i <= number )); do
    echo "DATE: ${i}" >> date.txt
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

```
#!/bin/bash

range=100
number=$((RANDOM % range))

for i in $(seq 0 $number); do
    echo "DATE: ${i}" >> date.txt
done
```

But all failed.

It outputs the following error message:

```
./task.sh: 7: [: Illegal number:
./task.sh: 7: [[: not found
./task.sh: 7: i: not found
```

I wonder how can I run a normal random for loop.

Best Regards!

EDIT)

```
#!/bin/bash

range=100
number=$((RANDOM % range))
i=0

while (( i <= number )); do
     echo "DATE: ${i}" >> date.txt
     i=$((i+1))
done
```

The above code works fine, but it only works once.
Unlike wanting to run `echo "DATE: ${i}" >> date.txt` randomly between 1 and 100, it is always executed only once. How can we resolve this problem?

Comment: The last one should have worked. `[[: not found`  and `i: not found` -> you are not running bash, you are running sh. `sh ./task.sh`. Bash != sh. `[: Illegal number:` Variable `i` is not set in first code snippet.

Comment: You can change `run: sh ./task.sh` to `run: bash ./task.sh` to run your script with bash. Your cron schedule (`0 0 * * *`) is set to run daily. You could change it to `0,30 * * * *`, to run every half an hour (the date will be the same all day though, unless you include the time, eg `date + '%Y-%m%d_%H:%M:%S'`). I'm not exactly sure what your goal is.

Comment: @dan Please reply to the answer, not the comment
Replacing `run: sh ./task.sh` with run: `bash ./task.sh` solved it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can change `run: sh ./task.sh` to `run: bash ./task.sh` to run your script with bash, instead of `sh`.
- If your script is executable (`chmod a+x task.sh`, and commit the file), and you have the right shebang (`#!/bin/bash`), you can also do `run: ./task.sh`.
- Your cron schedule (`0 0 * * *`) is set to run daily. If you want to run more frequently, you could change it. For example `0,30 * * * *` will run every half an hour (the date will be the same all day unless you include the time, eg `date + '%Y-%m%d_%H:%M:%S'`).