# how can I make a job in github action run randomly between 1 and 50 times a day?

Tags: bash, cron, sh, github-actions

how can I make a job in github action run randomly between 1 and 50 times a day?

Here is my cron job.

cron: '0 0 * * *'

This will run once a day.

But what I want is to run randomly 1-50 times a day.

How do I make it work randomly from 1 to 50?

below is my git action's yml setting file as workflows

```
#1. Repository Fork
# 2. Modify the files A and B according to the procedure
# 3. After committing the modifications, push & Enjoy!

name: planting-grass

# A. Comment lines 8-11
# on:
# push:
# branches:
# - unknown

# B. Uncomment lines 14-16
on:
   schedule:
     - cron: '0 0 * * *'

jobs:
  task:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set current date
        id: date
        run: echo "::set-output name=date::$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')"
      - name: Execute commands
        run: bash ./task.sh ${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}
      - name: Commit files
        run: |
          git config --global user.name "$(git --no-pager log --format=format:'%an' -n 1)"
          git config --global user.email "$(git --no-pager log --format=format:'%ae' -n 1)"
          git add date.txt
          git commit -m ${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}
      - name: Push changes
        uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          branch: ${{ github.ref }}
```

[Cron jobs and random times, within given hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049460/cron-jobs-and-random-times-within-given-hours) The method through this post does not work.

[image]

Best Regards!

Comment: Do you just care about the number of times that it runs, or do you also want it to run at random intervals?

Comment: @NickODell Only care about the number of times but should be randomly 1 to 50

Comment: See this article that might be helpful: https://code.mendhak.com/github-action-run-randomly-end-early/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by modifying your Bash script to loop a random number of times. For example, this Bash script loops between 1 and 50 times.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
loops=$(( ( RANDOM % 50 )  + 1 ))
echo "$loops"
for i in $(seq 1 $loops); do
    echo foo
done
```

The one downside of this approach is that you need to take the steps being done in the 'Commit files' step and merge them into the script in the 'Execute commands' step, or they won't be repeated.

Comment: In the git action environment, cannot run the yml environment inside the for statement.

Comment: True, but all of the things you're doing inside of the "Commit files" step are things you can do in Bash. Configuring Git? You can do that in Bash. Committing files? You can do that in Bash. Getting the date? You can do that in Bash.

Comment: result of this solution :
`./task.sh: 4: i: not found`

Comment: @emarwa.mouma.35t If you truly don't care about the intervals, this approach is best IMO. Once per day, the script/code runs between 1 and 50 times in a row. You can implement it as a wrapper script that calls `./task.sh` (instead of `echo foo`), or, add the loop to `task.sh`. I would use `for ((i=1; i<=loops; i++))` instead of `seq`, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: @emarwa.mouma.35t like the error in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69973005/how-can-i-randomly-run-for-loop-in-sh-of-git-action-normally), and my answer, you need to specify bash. Running `while (( i <= loops ))` (or similar) in `sh` will produce that error.

Answer (score -3):

To run a GitHub Action at a random time, you can use a combination of GitHub Actions and a script or action that generates a random delay. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

1. Create a workflow file (e.g., `.github/workflows/random-time.yml`) in your repository. This file defines the GitHub Action workflow.
2. Add the following content to the workflow file:

```yaml
name: Random Time Workflow
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 0 * * *'  # Run every day at midnight UTC

jobs:
  random-time-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Generate Random Delay
        id: random-delay
        run: echo "::set-output name=delay::$((RANDOM % 3600))"  # Generates a random delay between 0 and 3600 seconds

      - name: Wait for Random Delay
        run: sleep ${{ steps.random-delay.outputs.delay }}

      - name: Run Your Action
        run: |
          # Your action commands go here
```

In this example, the workflow is scheduled to run every day at midnight UTC (`0 0 * * *` in cron syntax). Adjust the cron expression according to your desired schedule.

3. The workflow contains three steps:

   - The first step generates a random delay using the `RANDOM` environment variable and sets the delay as an output variable.
   - The second step waits for the random delay using the `sleep` command.
   - The third step runs your desired action or commands.
4. Customize the third step by replacing `# Your action commands go here` with the actual commands or actions you want to run.
5. Commit and push the workflow file to your repository.

With this setup, the workflow will run at the scheduled time every day and introduce a random delay before executing your desired action or commands.

Comment: The question asks for multiple runs per day, but this approach will only run once per day.